# エラー文を解消したいです。object of type 'numpy.float128' has no len()

Tags: python, python3, numpy

python初心者です。
numpyで計算したnvという結果を棒グラフに表そうとしてます。

```
import numpy as np

nv_fw = np.longdouble(0)
nv_df = np.longdouble(0)
for trial in nv :
    for i in range(0,len(trial)-1):  
        nv_fw_dist = np.linalg.norm(trial.iloc[i,1:3]-trial.iloc[i+1, 1:3])

        nv_df_dist = np.linalg.norm(trial.iloc[i,3:5]-trial.iloc[i+1,3:5])

        if np.isnan(nv_df_dist):
            print(trial)
            break
        nv_fw += nv_fw_dist
        nv_df += nv_df_dist
       # print(nv_fw,   nv_df)

plt.bar(range(len(nv_fw)),nv_fw,color=[1,0,0])
```

このようにコードを書くと以下のようなエラーが表示されます。

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float128' has no len()
```

どのようにエラーを解消することができますでしょうk

Comment: `print(nv.shape)` の結果を教えてくださいませんか？

Answer (score 1):

おことわり：[質問に書かれたコードに変数nvなどを定義している部分が見当たらないので、推測を含んだ回答となっています]

```
for trial in nv :
    for i in range(0,len(trial)-1):
```

の"len(trial)"の部分で、「TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float128' has no len()」というエラーが発生する事から、
　・trialの型は、128bit浮動小数点数(longdouble)である。
　・nvは、longdoubleのリスト(配列）である。
という事が判ります。

そして、nvというリストの値をグラフに表すのであれば

```
plt.bar(range(0,len(nv)-1),nv)
```

で足ります。（x軸上の数値は、"0,1,2..."になります）

ところが、

```
nv_fw_dist = np.linalg.norm(trial.iloc[i,1:3]-trial.iloc[i+1, 1:3])
```

のように、nvが二次元配列のリストと想定されているようなコードも含まれています。

これらからアドバイスできることは、「nvの定義を見直すべき」です。
そして、見直し後のnvの定義に沿うようにコードを修正すれば、エラーはなくなると思います。

=== 質問者から 変数 nv について、以下のように回答がありましたので、回答に追記します(コードは読みやすいように整形しています) ===

```
nv= [] 
pattern = r'\d{1,2}(_0)' 
for file in os.listdir('./DATA.csv/'):
    if file.endswith('.csv')and re.match(pattern, file):
        nv.append(pd.read_csv('./DATA.csv/'+file,skiprows=2,usecols=[0,3,4,5,6]).dropna())
        print(re.match(pattern,file))
```

このコードから変数nvは、５つの値から成る配列の配列（[[1,2,3,4,5][1,2.3,4,6,3][3,4,11,2,9].....]のような感じ）だと判断できます。

===
ここで元のコードを最後のほうから見てゆきます。

```
plt.bar(range(len(nv_fw)),nv_fw,color=[1,0,0])
```

matplotlib.pyplot.bar の第１引数は各棒の位置(X軸）のリスト、第２引数は各棒の高さ(Y軸）のリスト(両方とも必須）なので

```
plt.bar(nv_fw,nv_df,color=[1,0,0])
```

というような感じで、nv_fwとnv_dfは数値の配列にしないといけない。

だから、

```
// 初期化
nv_fw = np.longdouble(0)
nv_df = np.longdouble(0)
// ループの内部
nv_fw += nv_fw_dist
nv_df += nv_df_dist
```

のように合計を求めてゆくのではなく、

```
// 初期化
nv_fw = []
nv_df = []
// ループの内部
nv_fw.append(nv_fw_dist)
nv_df.append(nv_df_dist)
```

のように数値をリストに追加していくようにしないといけない。

===
nvからデータを作っていくところは、nvの要素（５つの数値のリスト）を順に取り出して(nv[i])、さらに５つの数値のうちの最初の３つの差からnv_fw_distを、最後の３つの差からnv_df_distを、それぞれ二次元ノルム（ユークリッド・ノルム）を算出するようなので

```
for i in range(0,len(nv)-1): // iがnvの１次元のインデックスのループ（配列のインデックスは１ではなく0から始まることに注意）
    nv_fw_dist = np.linalg.norm(np[i][0:2]-np[i+1][0:2])
    nv_df_dist = np.linalg.norm(np[i][2:4]-np[i+1][2:4])
    nv_fw.append(nv_fw_dist)
    nv_df.append(nv_df_dist)
```

という感じかな。

＝＝　感想　＝＝
nvを定義するコードと、質問に書かれたコードは、相矛盾する箇所がいくつもあります。
そうした矛盾が解消できるように考えていった過程が、上に書いたような事です。

５つの数値から、３つの数値の組を２つ作る（１つの数値は両方の組で使われる）というのは、あまり見かけないデータ構造だと思います。
ひょっとすると、csvから６つの数値（nv_fw_dist用に３個、nv_df_dist用に３個）を取り出して、６個の数値のリストをつくるのではないのかなと思いました。

質問の最初に、そもそも何をするプログラムで、どんな意味を持つデータ(csvファイル）が入力として使われ、どんな出力を期待しているのか、といった情報があれば、良かったと思います。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。
nvの定義について書かせて頂きます。

nv= []
pattern = r'\d{1,2}(_0)'
for file in os.listdir('./DATA.csv/'):
    if file.endswith('.csv')and re.match(pattern, file):
        nv.append(pd.read_csv('./DATA.csv/'+file,skiprows=2,usecols=[0,3,4,5,6]).dropna())
        print(re.match(pattern,file))

このように、DATA.csvという名前のフォルダを読み込んでいます。

Comment: Fumu 7さん、nvの定義を説明させていただいた上で、nvの定義をどのように見直せばエラーが解消されますでしょうか。大変お手数ですが、よろしければお教えいただけたら光栄です

Comment: 非常に丁寧なご説明いただき誠にありがとうございます。
お陰様で無事解決することができました。